# Prove that the area of a triangle ABC can be found by the formula $\frac 12 \sqrt{\vec {AB^2}\cdot \vec {AC^2} - (\vec {AB} \cdot \vec {AC})^2}$

Tags: geometry, vectors

Prove that the area of a triangle ABC can be found by the formula $\frac 12 \sqrt{\vec {AB^2}\cdot \vec {AC^2} - (\vec {AB} \cdot \vec {AC})^2}$.

So, I drew the picture of triangle ABC as shown, and directed the vectors as shown ($\vec{AB}, \vec{AC}, \vec{CB}$).  Then, I construct a perpendicular vector $\vec{XB}$ to $\vec{AC}$.[image]

But no matter what manipulations I try, I can't seem to come up with this formula.  Note that the products are dot products and not cross-products.

I know that the sides of the triangle are $\vec{AB}$, $\vec{AC}$, and $\vec{CB}$, which equals $\vec{AB}-\vec{AC}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$2*area = base * heigth$
$area = AC \cdot XB = AC \cdot (AB \cdot sin(XÂB)) = AC \cdot AB \cdot \sqrt{1-cos(XÂB)²}
= \sqrt{AC²AB²-AC²AB²cos(XÂB)} = \sqrt{\vec{AB}²\vec{AC}² - (\vec {AB} \cdot \vec{AC})²}$

Comment: Of course!!  I completely neglected the fact that I could use the trigonometric Pythagorean identity.  Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac 12 \sqrt{\vec {AB^2}\cdot \vec {AC^2} - (\vec {AB} \cdot \vec {AC})^2}=
\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\vec {AB^2}\cdot \vec {AC^2}-\vec {AB^2}\cdot \vec {AC^2} \cos^2 A}=\frac{1}{2}|\vec{AB}||\vec{AC}|\sqrt{1-\cos^2 A}=\frac{1}{2}|\vec{AC}||\vec{AB}|\sin A=\frac{1}{2}(AC)(BX)=\textrm{Area of } ABC$$

Comment: I forgot to mention in the original that I was not supposed to use the cross-product.  But thank you for your help!